# regex to capture any http:// or http// links in JSON - Java 8 format

Tags: regex, json

I have some URLs like this

```
https://mega.nz/sometest
http://depositfiles.com/files/sometest
https://www.mediafire.com/file/aaaaaaaa/bbrtbrbrb_%iiiiiiii_.zip/file
```

I usually use

`(https?://mega\.nz[^>]+`)

but I try to capture all links and not only mega but replacing with

```
(https?://[^A-Za-z0-9]\.[^A-Za-z0-9_.][^>]+)
```

doesn't work.

I need to match all strings, that start with `http://` or `https://`

Comment: Between `https://` and domain `mega.nz` you can have username and password (if use sample authentication. Do you mean AFTER the domain?

Comment: @RomeoNinov nono, I have not username or password. I need to capture all kind of http links, not only mega.nz, but also mediafire, depositfiles etc

Comment: What do you need? `/sometest`, `/file/aaaaaaaa/bbrtbrbrb_%iiiiiiii_.zip/file`?

Comment: None of your examples has any text *between* :// and the domain name. What's your expected end result for these examples? That's really not clear.

Comment: @Tetsujin sorry, I think to explain bad: I need to match all strings, that start with `http://` or `https://` also if host name URL is different

Comment: What are the delimiters of the strings? `https?://\S+` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract the path and filename AFTER the protocol and domain name you can use something like:

```
(https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]*)(.*)
```

The second group will contain (based on your example):

```
/sometest
/files/sometest
/file/aaaaaaaa/bbrtbrbrb_%iiiiiiii_.zip/file
```

If you want to match all that begin with `http://` or `https://` you can use:

```
(https?:\/\/.*)
```

Comment: mm.. no, sorry, I think to explain bad: I need to match all strings, that start with `http://` or `https://`

Comment: @JackRock, see my edited answer

Comment: I need to write in JSON JAVA 8 format, look [here](https://board.jdownloader.org/showthread.php?p=509789) - I don't understand how to edit your regex to fix in json format

Comment: @JackRock, in such case will be better to ask your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/ and link current question for reference.